# Embedded vimeo videos will not play on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, embed, vimeo

Hers is the url: http://greyhawkfilms.com/whatwedo.html

It plays fine on the iPhone, but when I try to play it on the iPad only the audio plays and no video.

The embed code I'm using is here:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57884624" width="768px" height="432px" frameborder="10px" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by hiding the Vimeo player. I see that you do this in your code:

```
<div id="about-1-VP" style="display: none;">
  <div class="videoplayer">
    <div class="closevp"><a href="javascript:return:false"><span class="closevpbutton">(x) CLOSE</span></a>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/57884624" width="768" height="432" frameborder="10" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>4
```

To avoid this issue, try using another method to hide the iframe element instead of display:none, for example attaching a class that positions the element off-screen, eg

```
.special-hide
{
    position: absolute;
    left:-99999px;
}
```

Then remove the class when it's time to display the Vimeo player.